# How to organize my directories, subdirectories, files and CMakeLists.txt for CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran, libtorch

I want to compile a program using CMake in `Project/build/` directory having a following organization:

```
---Project/
   ---CMakeLists.txt
   ---main/
      ---main.f90
   ---library/
      ---CMakeLists.txt
      ---call_ts_module.f90
      ---call_ts.cpp
      ---call_ts.h
      ---torchscript.pt
      ---libtorch/
         ---<libtorch libraries>
   ---build/
```

The main Fortran program `Project/main/main.f90` calls `call_ts_subroutine` defined in module `Project/library/call_ts_module.f90`, which calls a c++ function `invariant_nn` defined in `Project/library/call_ts.cpp` and `Project/library/call_ts.h`, which invoke a torchscript `Project/library/torchscript.pt`.
How should `Project/CMakeLists.txt` and `Project/library/CMakeLists.txt` look like? I tried following ones (I am totally new to CMake), but they did not work (`make` does not see the header file `call_ts_export.h`):

`Project/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(fortran_calls_ts CXX Fortran)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")
endif()
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_RELEASE "-O3")
find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
add_subdirectory(library)
add_executable(fortran_calls_ts.x main/main.f90)
target_link_libraries(fortran_calls_ts.x library)
set_property(TARGET fortran_calls_ts.x PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

`Project/library/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
add_library(library SHARED call_ts_module.f90)
add_library(call_ts_cpp SHARED call_ts.cpp)
target_link_libraries(library call_ts_cpp)
target_link_libraries(call_ts_cpp "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
include(GenerateExportHeader)
generate_export_header(call_ts_cpp BASE_NAME call_ts)
install(TARGETS call_ts_cpp LIBRARY DESTINATION lib ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES call_ts.h ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/call_ts_export.h DESTINATION include)
```

`Project/main/main.f90`

```
program main
    
    use call_ts_module
    ...
    call call_ts_subroutine()
    ...

end program main
```

`Project/library/call_ts_module.f90`

```
module call_ts_module
    
    contains
    
    subroutine call_ts_subroutine()
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_float
        implicit none
        interface invariant_nn
            subroutine invariant_nn(I, G) bind (c)
                import :: c_float
                real(c_float) :: I(5)
                real(c_float) :: G(10)
            end subroutine
        end interface

        real(4) I(5), G(10)
        ...
        call invariant_nn(I, G)
        ...
    end subroutine call_ts_subroutine

end module call_ts_module
```

`Project/library/call_ts.cpp`

```
#include "call_ts.h"
#include <torch/script.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

void invariant_nn(float I[], float G[])
{
    torch::jit::script::Module module;
    const char *arg;
    arg = "../library/torchscript.pt";
    module = torch::jit::load(arg);
    std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> inputs;
    float data[] = {I[0], I[1], I[2], I[3], I[4]};
    inputs.push_back(torch::from_blob(data, {1, 5}));
    at::Tensor outputs = module.forward(inputs).toTensor();
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        G[k] = outputs[0][k].item().to<float>();
    }
    return;
}
```

`Project/library/call_ts.h`

```
#pragma once

#ifndef CALL_TS_API
#include "call_ts_export.h"
#define CALL_TS_API CALL_TS_EXPORT
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

CALL_TS_API
void invariant_nn(float I[], float G[]);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Have a look at my project - https://github.com/VeriBlock/alt-integration-cpp/ it may inspire you.